# Что значит строчка кода?

Tags: javascript

Есть код, который при вводе в input прерывает вызов функции callSearch, если после последнего ввода символа не прошло 2х секунд, помогите разобраться с данными строчками:

```
let logger = (args) => callSearch(args);
```

и debounce эта функция, и можно ли упростить данный пример?

```js
      var lastCall = false; var lastCallTimer;  

     $('.target').keyup(function(){
     var Value = $('input').val(); 
     let logger = (args) => callSearch(args);
      let debouncedLogger = debounce(logger, 2000);
      debouncedLogger(Value);

  });

    function debounce(f, t) {
        return function(args) {
            let previousCall = lastCall;
            lastCall = Date.now();
            if (previousCall && ((lastCall - previousCall) <= t)) {
                clearTimeout(lastCallTimer);
            }
            lastCallTimer = setTimeout(() => f(args), t);
        }
    }

    function callSearch(args)
    {
     console.log(args);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="" name="" class='target'>
```

Comment: В переменную logger = мы присваиваем стрелучную функцию , которая вызивает callSearch().
https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/428566/

Comment: _помогите разобраться с данными строчками_ - только с одной строчкой `let logger = ...`? или еще с какими-то?